# Changing thumbnail for Facebook previews in comments

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When posting a link in a **comment** on a Facebook post, there's a small square thumbnail included in the link preview. My preview images are usually rectangular and so Facebook selects how to crop this into a square for the link preview. I've noticed in some images, there is a detectable person in the image and so the crop is taken around that. However, in other images where the content isn't entirely clear, the crop is just taken from the centre of the image, leaving the image empty as my content is usually on the sides.

The crop seems to be done using some parameters (sx sy sw sh), in the facebook comment itself:

center crop:

```
https://external-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDVaAOputB_VkrO&w=90&h=90&url=...&cfs=1&upscale=1&_nc_hash=...
```

right crop:

```
https://external-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAny2E3bpUGVeYX&w=90&h=90&url=...&cfs=1&upscale=1&sx=280&sy=0&sw=396&sh=396&_nc_hash=...
```

**Is there a way to choose the square crop parameter values for the link preview?** I can't see an option to do this from the debugging tools (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), and I can't see any options when actually posting the link in a Facebook comment. Perhaps there's a way to control this using the image alt tag? I have not seen anything in the Facebook API that might help. I understand I can change the preview image to a square but I don't want to take that route unless I have to.

Comment: No, you can not specify that in any way. You could try and embed two og:image elements, and hope Facebook picks the right one according to the display situation.

Comment: I thought there might be a way to indicate to FB where the point of interest is in the image - it does seem to try to detect a person and crop around that.

Answer (score 0):

you should create your image using Photoshop or Canva and design it with your own aspect ratio  https://joezdesign.wordpress.com/